# Android 3D button text position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

How to change text position for different button states?

On image you can see how its look like now:

[image: incorrect button states text position]

**drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:top="4dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#DCDBDB" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#B1B1B1"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:bottom="4.5dp" android:left="1.5dp" android:right="1.5dp" android:top="5.5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:gravity="bottom">
                    <solid android:color="#F2F1F1" />
                    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#DCDBDB" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#B1B1B1"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:bottom="8.5dp" android:left="1.5dp" android:right="1.5dp" android:top="1.5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#F2F1F1" />
                    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Few days ago I asked similar question - [Android 3D button src padding](/questions/21079077/android-3d-button-src-padding), but for text I cant use this trick :/ (or dont know how).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a custom `Button` and override the methods for changing it's state in order to customize it's gravity based on the current state.

For example here is the code for a custom `Button` whose text will jump to the bottom when it is pressed:

```
public class VariableGravityButton extends Button {
    public VariableGravityButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VariableGravityButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VariableGravityButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        if (pressed != isPressed()) {
            setGravity(pressed ? Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL |
                    Gravity.BOTTOM : Gravity.CENTER);
        }
        super.setPressed(pressed);
    }
}
```

Comment: can I do it just with XML?

Comment: @Shaddow: No, you can't. Only drawables and colors can define state lists.

Comment: OK I tried your code (but as usually, I have problems :/) Its set just BOTTOM gravity, so when I press, text is in bottom-left corner.

Comment: `setGravity(pressed ? Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM : Gravity.CENTER);` is working :)

Comment: @Shaddow: It seems you omitted `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` from my code. Your way works too.

Comment: no, `Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL` doesnt work and `Gravity.CENTER` do, dont know why, but its happen

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I should have used `CENTER_HORIZONTAL` :)

Comment: My last question is, its possible do it without `minHeight` or do it more dynamic? Because now I have to calculate this value from font size, paddings, ...

Comment: @Shaddow: You will have to define a `minHeight`, unless you rely on the background drawable to define the minimum size, which would require using bitmap or nine-patch files.