# Move text in android Button on click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drawable

I have a button with some shapes as a background so basically I want to move the text a little bit to the bottom so it makes a 3D effect

---

Here is an image of my button

### [image: My button]

Left(not clicked) and Right(clicked). Please ignore click circle.

Selector XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_red_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_red_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_red_focused" />
</selector>
```

Normal state drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_radius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/red" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_radius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Pressed state drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_radius" />
</shape>
```

Is it possible to make the text move to the bottom just with XML?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21223137/2435238

Comment: I recommend to set text inside drawable.xml like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850431/how-do-you-render-text-in-an-android-layer-list-xml-file

Comment: I have investigated this painful process as well. You have to extend your own custom button to support a padding change for the text on press events. Also text is centred on the entire button including shadow which makes the text look off-centre to the user. This physical effect is a 90's Windows button style. Although, dated this effect is still relevant that could be used with a style refresh.